# ProgressRing only showing after Button_Click function is done

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a function:

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    progressRing.IsActive = true;

    // my code

    progressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    progressRing.IsActive = false;
}
```

The progress ring will not show at all. If I don't hide the progress ring at the end of my function it will show but only after the AppBarButton_Click has ended. How do I get the progress ring to show immediately?

Comment: The problem is that `// my code` is blocking the update. Read up on async events.

Comment: Does that mean I have to go async completely with all my code?

Comment: Thanks did some reading I got it now. Great!